# How to set permissions or alter a git commit process when using local repositories

Tags: git

I have a server that contains a central git repository and one of my co-worker's development environment.  My co-worker's repository's origin is the central git repository and he pushes there when he has some code to share.  Likewise, I develop locally and push to the central git repository when I have some code to share, so my repository's origin is also the central git repository.

The issue is that I have the central git repository under a "git" user's home directory.  So when I push I am actually SSH'ing into the the server as the "git" user.  To be even more clear, my config has these lines:

```
$ more .git/config 
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = git@development.mydomain.com:fsg
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

When I push, git handles this SSH + push seamlessly with I am guessing some sort of git shell.  The issue is that when my coworker pushes, he is logged in as himself for a user and gets a bunch of crazy permission errors.  Is there a typical way to solve this problem without opening up git's directories to a group?  I think this will be problematic when I push and therefore overwrite the the repository and those permissions are reset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coworker could change the origin of his development environment to use an SSH URL instead of a local filesystem URL, so that when he pushes, he's actually SSH'ing into the server as the `git` user. It shouldn't be a problem that both the client and the server in that connection are the same computer.

I *believe* this can be done using

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@server/path
git remote set-url --push origin ssh://git@server/path
```

but I have never done this myself so if you try it, I strongly recommend testing on a throwaway repository first.

*EDIT*: Or just

```
git config --replace-all remote.origin.url ssh://git@server/path
```

I think.

Comment: and btw, the way to simply test that is do "git push your_ssh_line master" ...because in the end it's just an alias

Comment: FYI - I am giving you +1 because using 127.0.0.1 as the domain worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than logging in with the same user, we wanted to have our own logins and then set the permissions after the push. This was easily done with setting up a group that all developers are members of and then using the post-receive hook to set the group on the objects.The following is in `/path/to/repo.git/hooks/post-receive`:

```
chgrp -R git /path/to/repo.git/objects
```

Be sure that the hook script has execute permissions set so this will run on successful push to the central repo.

My environment

- git 1.7.3.2
- RHEL 5.3